# Django enctype="multipart/form-data" not setting POST data

Tags: django, file-upload

I need to send both a file and some data from input texts.

This is the form I'm working on:

```
    <form method="post" action="{% url catalog_create_ajax_upload %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="create-form">
        <input type="text" id="new-catalog-name" name="catalog_name" class="large-input" placeholder="catalog title" />
        <div id="new-catalog">
            <input type="file" name="file">
        </div>
    </form>
```

When sent, I excpect `request.POST['catalog_name']`to have a value, but the whole POST attribute in an empty dictionary.

Any help?

Comment: no errors, just the empty dictionary

Comment: If you inspect the request payload being sent with e.g. Chrome Developer tools, do you see the "catalog_name" argument?

Comment: request.POST[input[name='catalog_name']].. see whether this helps...

Comment: in the views, are you doing a Form(request.POST, request.FILES) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to have a submit button in that form. Presumably you've got one elsewhere on the page, but it would only submit the fields in its own form - move it inside that `<form>...</form>`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your view function should get the image file like this

```
def index(request):
    image = 'file' in request.FILES and request.FILES['file']
```

Use `request.FILES` instead of `request.POST`